# Get PDF of the current page in a Google Chrome extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

There is [code in Chromium](http://code.google.com/searchframe#OAMlx_jo-ck/src/chrome/browser/resources/print_preview/) that's used for generating a PDF version of the current page, before displaying it in Print Preview.

Is it possible for a Chrome extension to access this API, to get a PDF version of the current page?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Chrome does not offer any such API for extensions.

If your aim is to generate PDF files using Chrome, you can do that by `Print > Destination > Save as PDF`.

Answer (score 5):

You can use page [Capture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture.html) which returns page data as [M HTML blob](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture.html#method-saveAsMHTML) and then convert  [MTHML blob to PDF](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mhtml+to+pdf).

### References:

- [Page Capture API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/pageCapture.html)
- [MHTML to PDF](https://www.google.co.in/search?q=mhtml%20to%20pdf)

Let me know if you need more information.

Comment: The Capture API looks like the way forward, thanks - perhaps PDF will be added as an option there in the future. I also found [chrome.tabs.captureVisibleTab](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-captureVisibleTab) which can capture as PNG or JPEG.